# Finding the frequent words in a text file, error in the order and counts

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to find top k most frequent words in a csv file. Original file is csv and it has over 1M lines so I skipped some phases for focusing the problem area.

Before that I solved punctuation ,make it all lowercase so in test text there is only words and numbers, and when I'm parsing the data I skip numbers too.

Here is my code:
header-->

> ```
> #pragma once
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <string>
> #include <assert.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> using namespace std;
> struct sitecount
> {
>   string name = " ";
>   int count = 0;
>   bool first_ten_rank = 0;
> };
>
> class site
> {
> private:
>   int size = 14717;
>   sitecount site_placement[14717];
>   sitecount* rankings[10];
>
> public:
>   site();
>   site(string);
>   void add(string);
>   void sort_rank();
>   void check_ten(int);
>   void print_ten() const;
>   int getSize();
>   int find(string) const;
>   int dh(string, int) const;
>   int dhash1(string) const;
>   int dhash2(string) const;
>
>
>
> };
> ```

cpp-->

> ```
> site::site()
> {}
> int site::dh(string n, int i) const
> {
>   return abs(dhash1(n) + i * dhash2(n)) % size;
> }
> int site::dhash1(string name) const
> {
>   int site_res = 7;
>   for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
>       site_res = (site_res * 31 + name[i]) % 1000000;
>   return abs(site_res) % size;
> }
> int site::getSize()
> {
>   return size;
> }
> int site::dhash2(string name) const
> {
>   int site_res = 7;
>   for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
>       site_res = (site_res * 31 + name[i]) % 1000000;
>   return 1 + (abs(site_res) % (size - 1));
> }
> int site::find(string name) const
> {
>   int i = 0;
>   int check_pl = dh(name, i);
>   while (site_placement[check_pl].count != 0 || i == size)
>   {
>       if (site_placement[check_pl].name == name)
>           return check_pl;
>       i++;
>       check_pl = dh(name, i);
>   }
>   return -1;
> }
> void site::add(string name)
> {
>   int first_check = find(name);
>   if (first_check == -1)
>   {
>       int i = 0;
>       int place = dh(name, i);
>       while (site_placement[place].count != 0)
>       {
>           i += 1;
>           place = dh(name, i);
>       }
>       site_placement[place].name = name;
>       site_placement[place].count = 1;
>       check_ten(place);
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       site_placement[first_check].count++;
>       check_ten(first_check);
>   }
> }
> void site::check_ten(int place)
> {
>   if (site_placement[place].first_ten_rank)
>   {
>       sort_rank();
>       return;
>   }
>   else if (rankings[0]->count > site_placement[place].count)
>       return;
>   rankings[0] = &site_placement[place];
>   site_placement[place].first_ten_rank = 1;
>   sort_rank();
> }
> void site::print_ten() const
> {
>   cout << "RANKINGS" << "- - -" << "SITE" << "- - -" << "HIT" << endl;
>   for (int i = 9; i > -1; i--)
>
>       cout << 10 - i << "-)" << "- - -" << rankings[i]->name << "- - -" << rankings[i]->count << "- - -" << endl;
> }
> void site::sort_rank()
> {
>   sitecount* temp;
>   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
>   {
>       int j = i;
>       while (j > 0 && (rankings[j - 1]->count) > (rankings[j]->count))
>       {
>           temp = rankings[j];
>           rankings[j] = rankings[j - 1];
>           rankings[j - 1] = temp;
>           j--;
>       }
>   }
> }
> site::site(string file_name)
> {
>   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>       rankings[i] = &site_placement[i];
>   ifstream a;
>   string s;
>   s.clear();
>   a.open(file_name.c_str());
>   assert(a.is_open() == 1 && "File could not be found");
>   string one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero;
>   one = "1"; two = "2"; three = "3"; four = "4"; five = "5";
>   six = "6"; seven ="7"; eight = "8"; nine = "9"; zero = "0";
>   while (a>>s ) {
>       if(!(s.length()==0)&& s.compare(one)&& s.compare(two)&& s.compare(three)&& s.compare(four)&& s.compare(five)
>           && s.compare(six)&& s.compare(seven)&& s.compare(eight)&& s.compare(nine)&&s.compare(zero))
>       add(s);
>   }
>   a.close();
> }
> ```

main--->

> ```
> #include "site.h"
> #include <time.h>
> using namespace std;
> int main()
> {
>   const clock_t begin_time = clock();
>   site my_site("output.txt");
>   my_site.print_ten();
>   clock_t end_time2 = clock();
>   cout << "It took : " << end_time2 - begin_time << " milliseconds" << endl;
>   system("PAUSE");
>
>   return 0;
>
> }
> ```

the text file-->  https://textuploader.com/d8xwi!

```
My results
1) love--31
2) kindle2--20
3) latex--10
4) tek--8
5) lt3--5
6) cool--4
7) lot--4
8) blah--3
9) card--3
10)favorite--2

True results

time    48
night   37
good    34
warner  34
love    31
museum  26
nike    26
im  26
gm  22
jquery  21
twitter 20
lebron  20
great   20
google  20
safeway 20
kindle2 20
hate    19
rt  19
today   19
watch   18
api 16
day 15
amp 15
atampt  15
work    14
```

Comment: Move your code on stackoverflow

Comment: Links, over time, disappear. You should show your code here. Just indent it by 4 characters.

Comment: I expect that the task at hand "finding the frequent words in a text file", should take at most a dozen or so lines of code, instead of this lengthy detour in the land of buggy hashing and magical constants; and it still fails all the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. It's going to faster to get rid of all of this, and start everything from scratch. The end result should only be a dozen or so lines of code: a `std::map`, a loop to reach each word, lowercase it, increment the map counter. After eof, invert the map, sort by highest count. The End.

Comment: might as well post site.h too at this point.  After all, how do we know how big your array declarations are?

Comment: In `site::find` , shouldn't it be `i != size` ?

Comment: When I changed it like that execution never ending.

Comment: @A.Sky Use a `std::map<std::string,int>` to realize that. Sop using raw arrays and trying to do memory management yourself unless you are a 100% sure your implementation performs better than what's already offered from the c++ standard library.

Comment: Try `... && i != size`

Comment: I can't use map its forbidden

Comment: When you answer someone, you should begin with @Name ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a site is removed from the top ten list, its flag `first_ten_rank` must be reset to zero or it will never re-enter the top ten again.

```
void site::check_ten(int place)
{
  if (site_placement[place].first_ten_rank)
  {
      sort_rank();
      return;
  }
  else if (rankings[0]->count > site_placement[place].count)
      return;

  //When a site is removed from the top ten list, its first_ten_rank must be set to zero.
  //otherwise, a removed one from topten list will never enter the topten again
  rankings[0]->first_ten_rank = 0;

  rankings[0] = &site_placement[place];
  site_placement[place].first_ten_rank = 1;
  sort_rank();
}
```